# Homology of an edge with the endpoints identified

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence, simplicial-complex

I was studying Mayer Vietoris Long Exact Sequence. To get my hands dirty I wanted to try some examples: let $L$ be two points and $K$ be two points connected with an edge, in euclidean space. My aim is to compute homology of $K/L$ via this technique.

More precisely, let $L = \{\{u\},\{v\}\}$ and $K = \{\{u\},\{v\}, \{u,v\}\}$ be two simplical complexes.

Now my understanding of $0^{th}$ and $1^{st}$ homology groups is that, they represent connected components and tunnels, respectively. In particular, $K/L$ is a loop and so it has one connected component and one tunnel and hence I would expect the relative homology to be $H_0(K,L) = \mathbb{F} = H_1(K,L)$ and $H_i(K,L) = 0$ for $i \geq 2$.

I will now attempt to do the computations to see if this is true indeed: We have the following short exact sequence $0 \to C_d(L) \to C_d(K) \to C_d(K,L) \to 0$ for each $d \geq 0$. This gives rise to the long exact sequence  $0 \to H_1(K,L) \to H_0(L) \to H_0(K) \to H_0(K,L) \to 0$.

Here we have $H_0(L) = \mathbb{F}^2$, $H_0(K) = \mathbb{F}$ and $H_0(L) \to H_0(K)$ is a rank $1$ map. Which gives $H_1(K,L) = \mathbb{F}$ but $H_0(K,L) = 0$!

First I doubted my calculations but then we do have $C_0(K,L) = C_0(K)/C_0(L) = 0$ and $C_1(K,L) = C_1(K)/C_1(L) = \mathbb{F}$, so my computation seems correct, right?

How is $K/L$ different from, say the graph $K_3$ or $S^1$ geometrically? This has left me questioning my intuition and I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand this. Also, I would like to ask what is it exactly that the zeroth homology group represent here?

Comment: $(K,L)$ is a so-called good pair, so the relative homology can be identified with the reduced homology of the quotient $K/L$. Informally, in reduced homology you "lose" one copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $H_0$, so that connected spaces have trivial homology in degree $0$.

Comment: @DouglasMolin I see. But where did reduced homology enter into the picture? Could you also elaborate on "good pair" in an answer, or perhaps point to me some references? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your confusion is coming from mixing up the homology of $K/L$ and the homology of the pair $(K,L)$; they're not quite the same.

First, your computation is correct: $H_0(K,L) \cong 0$, $H_1(K,L) \cong \mathbb{F}$, and all other homology groups are zero.

When you earlier try to intuit the homology groups, you actually correctly guessed the homology groups of $K/L$ (which is indeed homeomorphic to $S^1$), with $H_0$ and $H_1$ rank $1$ and all other homology groups zero. So there is a difference between $H_*(K,L)$ and $H_*(K/L)$.

Relative homology of a pair $(X,A)$ is capturing "homology of $X$ modulo $A$." That is, an element of $H_k(X,A)$ is a $k$-chain in $X$ whose boundary lies in $A$, and is trivial if it is the boundary of a $(k+1)$-chain in $X$ (modulo the subgroup $C_k(A)$). Thus $H_0(X,A)$ is free of rank equal to the number of path components of $X$ that do not intersect $A$.

Relative homology of a pair $(X,A)$ is almost the same as the homology of the quotient $X/A$. If the pair $(X,A)$ satisfies the hypotheses that $A$ is closed and nonempty and there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $A$ in $X$ such that $U$ deformation retracts to $A$ (this is referred to in various places as a "good pair" or an "NDR pair" (stands for 'neighborhood deformation retract'), and is also equivalent to the requirement that the inclusion $A \to X$ is a cofibration), then excision of singular homology is equivalent to the statement that $H_k(X,A) \cong \tilde{H}_k(X/A)$. An important thing to note is that when the pair $(X,A)$ consists of a (simplicial, CW) complex and a subcomplex, the pair always satisfies this hypothesis.

Since reduced homology coincides with absolute homology above degree zero, we have $H_1(K,L) \cong H_1(K/L)$. In view of this theorem, the difference between $H_0(K,L)$ and $H_0(K/L)$ is precisely one factor of $\mathbb{F}$ since $H_0(K/L) \cong \tilde{H}_0(K/L) \oplus \mathbb{F}$ and $K/L$ is path-connected so $H_0(K/L) \cong \mathbb{F}$, giving $0 = \tilde{H}_0(K/L) \cong H_0(K,L)$.

References for these facts can probably be found in most books on singular homology or introductory algebraic topology books. I only know the specific locations of references from Hatcher's book, so: discussion of relative homology is in section 2.1 (pages 115-116), the theorem establishing equivalence of relative homology of an NDR pair and the reduced homology of the quotient is proposition 2.22, and the fact that a CW pair $(X,A)$ with $A$ nonempty is always an NDR pair follows from proposition A.5 or 0.16.

Comment: This is a great answer and cleared my doubt. Thank you so much!